# Why was my interview schedule cut short?

Tags: interviewing, united-states, california, onsite

I went through the following process:
Phone interview with recruiter (who reached out to me initially)
Phone interview with hiring manager
On site interview (which involved me flying coast to coast)

Prior to arriving to my on-site interview, I was given the itinerary for it, which indicated that I was to have 6 interviews on-site. However, after the end of my 3rd interview, my on-site contact picked me up and told me that the interviews were over and walked me out of the building. I was somewhat surprised, so I didn’t have the presence of mind to ask what was going on in the moment. Upon reflection, I can’t imagine this would be anything but bad news, but I have no idea why this happened. Each of the 3 interviews that I had went really well, I didn’t lie on my resume about anything, I didn’t say anything that was offensive, etc… so I am simply at a loss for why this happened. I’m sure I’ll get an explanation within a week or so (via an offer/no offer decision) but it really sucks in the moment. Is this common? I’ve never experienced this before.

Comment: Why so many down votes? Sure no one will know why they had the interview cut short but the problem itself is quite straightforward to solve right for more experienced people.

Comment: Your interviews may have gone well, but interviews with other candidates may have gone even better.

Comment: there might be a reason to cut short your interview is that they might get the suitable candidate for the job they are looking for they can't say no to your face and they won't be wasting your time or their time if they got the candidate. or in some case, if the company pull back there position or they decide they don't want new hire after all.

Answer (score 2):

No one can say why it was cut short except for the company itself. Ask for feedback. Its reasonable to do so and a good company will provide feedback proportional to the effort the candidate had put in. Having said that a good company wouldn't cut an interview short like this without explaining on the spot.
There are definitely interviews where you know the candidate is amazing or terrible half way through. Its very unusual to cancel the interview though. It is quite rude especially if they have travelled to be there.
However, you are correct that the signs are generally bad. A good candidate is unlikely to be so good they cut short the thing without at least saying.